# Objects of wrong entity fetched from CoreData relationship

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a rather big CoreData Model which suddenly behaves weirdly. There are three relevant entities:

- User
- Story
- Group

`User` has a to-many relationship named `stories` to `Story` objects and a to-many-relationship `groups` to `Group` objects. Both also have an appropriate inverse. I use mogenerator to generate convenience accessors for all the properties and relationships. Both are ordered to-many relationships.

Now it sometimes happens that when I ask the user object for its `groups` (like `user.groups`) that I actually get an NSOrdered set of XNGStory objects. In the few cases that I have observed this they were the same objects that are returned by `user.stories`. The two sets weren't the same (different pointers), but their contents were (I checked by calling `array] valueForKeyPath:@"objectID.URIRepresentation"]` on them and got the same URIs in the same order both cases).

It feels like there is some way in my app that stores stories in the `groups` relationship but I checked the code and there are only Groups-related classes touching `groups` relationship and only story-related classes touching the `story`-relationship. Also there is no interaction or relationship between the two they are used in completely separate parts of the app, so I have no idea how this kind of data corruption can happen.

Is there any reason why such a data corruption might happen? I would have expected CoreData to complain when I store objects in the wrong kind of relationship accidentally.

One more thing: So far we were only able to reproduce it on iOS 10.

#### Things we tried:

- We suspected a memory issue first (because an object of the wrong type turns up where it's not supposed to be), but running with Address Sanitizer and NSZombies enabled didn't reveal any issues. Also, once the issue occurs it persists over app restarts and using the debugger to poke around in the objects also shows a consistent(ly wrong) data model so it's not just one pointer that's wrong.
- Deactivated [WAL](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) (issue still exists)
- Looked at sqlite file (both with and without WAL) after crash with [Core Data Editor](https://github.com/ChristianKienle/Core-Data-Editor): It displays Group-objects for the `groups` relationship, so all seems to be good on the sqlite-database-level -> Somehow the relationships get mixed up when loaded from the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As best I can tell, this seems to be an iOS 10 bug.

We have a similar problem with an app that uses Core Data - a User object has a relationship Addresses (to Address objects) and Friends (to other User objects).

For some reason under iOS 10 Core Data occasionally chooses to return the Address objects in the Friends relationship.

We've regression tested back to iOS 9 and this issue doesn't occur.

There's an open bug on Open Radar for the same issue - [26826183](https://openradar.appspot.com/26826183).  Interestingly we've only started seeing this issue under 10.0.2 but that Radar report was based on an early iOS 10 Beta.

Comment: I am getting reports from users of an app that Core Data is having errors  and unable to fetch data.  Both users have 10.0.2 installed.

Answer (score 0):

We have tested this extensively and also conclude that it is an iOS 10 bug. It also does not seem to be related to any of our code, just the data model. We were able to recreate the issue in an example project using our data model, Xcode 8's code generation and iOS 10's new `NSPersistentContainer` (before it broke using mogenerator and the "old way of setting up a CoreData stack").

To reproduce the issue we do the following:

1. At startup, if there is no `User`-object, create a `User`-object and add 10 `Group` objects to it and save.
2. Then add a `Story` to it, still on the main-context, and save.
3. Kill the app (via iOS swipe-up or simply via pressing "stop" in Xcode)
4. Start the app again. On startup, fetch the `User` object, add a `Story` object to to the `stories` relationship and save.
5. Check the `user.groups` relationship on a background or main context. It contains `XNGStory` objects now, although it should still have `XNGGroup` objects.

I filed a Radar with the example project. OpenRadar is [here](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6073623597023232) (without the example project, as it contains our data model).

The issue seems to be highly dependent on the data-model setup. It occurs when all-but-on relationships on our `User` entity are ordered. If all are ordered, it doesn't occurs, neither does it occur if two or more are unordered.